# how do you make a controller in F# that uses hyphens?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, f#

I have a .net MVC website and my controllers are written in f#. But I'm having trouble finding out how to use hyphens in my controllers.

I want something like:

domain.com/some-cool-page

How is this done in F#?

Here's an example of my contact controller:

```ml
type ContactController() =
inherit Controller()
member x.Index () =
    let version = typeof<int * int>.Assembly.GetName().Version
    let msg = sprintf "This web page is running using F# version %s." (version.ToString(4))
    x.ViewData.["Message"] <- msg

    let uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    let param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("id") 
    x.ViewData.["idinfo"] <- param1
    x.View("~/Views/contact.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it with routing configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CoolPage",
    "some-cool-page/{action}/{id}",
    { controller = "Contact"; action = "Index"; id = UrlParameter.Optional }
) |> ignore
```

Add this before the "Default" route, and you can access the ContactsController and the appropriate view via `/some-cool-page`.

You'll typically find the routing configuration in your global.asax.fs file, depending on the template you're using.

Comment: This isn't f#. I know I could do it in C#, but I want F# like my other controllers.

Comment: Woops, sorry. I would like to have it in the same file as my other controllers. Not in the main global.asax file. Is this possible?